# Domain of Inverse Trig Function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I was asked to find the domain of $$\arcsin[\frac{x^2+1}{2x}]$$
My first step was $$-1\leq\frac{x^2+1}{2x} \leq1$$

What I don't understand is why I cannot cross multiply to get $$-2x\le {1+x}^{2} \le 2x$$ and then solve the inequality? I tried doing this and got the wrong answer.

Comment: You need to separate the problem into two cases: where $x$ is positive, and where $x$ is negative. This is because multiplying by a negative number flips the sign of the inequality.

Comment: Your last inequality hold only for $x>0$. If $x<0$, you should reverse the signs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the domain, you need to check every possible real value of $x$. This includes values of $x$ where $x\ge 0$ and where $x<0$. When you multiplied all three terms of

$$-1\leq\frac{x^2+1}{2x} \leq1$$

by $2x$ to form

$$-2x\le {1+x}^{2} \le 2x$$

you only considered the case where $x\ge 0$. Since an inequality flips sign when multiplied by a negative number, multiplying all of the terms of

$$-1\leq\frac{x^2+1}{2x} \leq1$$

by $2x$ when $x<0$ forms

$$-2x\ge {1+x}^{2} \ge 2x$$

Therefore, you need to break up the analysis into two cases and consider what happens when $x\ge 0$ and $x<0$.

Case 1: Suppose $x\ge 0$. Then

$$-2x\le {1+x}^{2} \le 2x$$

by the second inequality

$${1+x}^{2} \le 2x$$

we see that $x=1$ is the only solution.

Case 2: Suppose $x < 0$. Then

$$-2x\ge {1+x}^{2} \ge 2x$$

where from the first inequality

$$1+x^2 \le -2x$$

we have that $x=-1$ is the only solution.

So, the domain of $\arcsin\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)$ is $x\in\{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\tan y$

$z=\arcsin\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}=\arcsin(\csc2y)$

$\implies\sin z=\csc2y$ which is either $\ge1$ or $\le-1$

But $-1\le\sin z\le1$

So, $\dfrac{1+x^2}{2x}=\pm1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\arcsin\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}$

$x^2-2x\sin y+1=0$

$x=\sin y\pm i\cos y$

As $x$ is real, $\cos y$ must be $0$

$\implies\sin y=\pm1$